# problems with a component with angular google charts inserted multiple times in another

Tags: angular-google-chart

I have this component

```
<div class="grafica">
  <google-chart #chart [title]="title" [type]="type" [data]="data" [options]="options" [width]="800" [height]="500">
  </google-chart>
</div>

import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grafica',
  templateUrl: './grafica.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grafica.component.scss']
})
export class GraficaComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() type: string;
  @Input() data: any[][];

  options: any;


  constructor() { }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log('GraficaComponent-ngOnChanges-data', this.data);
  }


ngOnInit(): void {

this.options = {
  hAxis: {
    title: 'Años',
  },
  vAxis: {
    minValue: 0,
  },
  legend: { position: 'top' },
};
}
}
```

And I use it inside another component

```
....
<app-grafica [title]="'Ofertas Presentadas y Adjudicadas'" [type]="'ColumnChart'"
    [data]="dataPorcentajeAdjudicadas"></app-grafica>

<app-grafica [title]="'Costes y Horas'" [type]="'ColumnChart'"   [data]="dataHorasCostesOfertas"></app-grafica>
```

When debugging I see that the correct data arrives separately to the graphic component

[image]

But only the first set of data is represented well to me

[image]

The second one does this to me

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks